# Iterate through attributes of xml using python and write to multiple files

Tags: python, xml

In the following XML file,

```
<Traces general_diff="0" z_array="0" s_array="0" w_array="0" etch_factor="0.35" TS_track2track="0" TS_DQS="0" TW_DQS="0" TS_byte2dqs="0" TS_byte2byte="0" TS_DQ="0" TW_DQ="0" dsl_offset="0" D="20" TS="7" TW="5"/>
```

I am trying to iterate the value of TS,TW and D from given ranges through python. But when I run the code below, `child.set('TS',i)` throws an error `Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'int'`
How do I pass the variable i so that the values are iterated? 
Also after iterating, I want to write it into files equal to the number of iterations.

```
 for child in root.iter('Traces'):
        child.find('D')
        child.find('TS')
        child.find('TW')
        for i in frange(3,12.75,0.25):
            child.set('TS',i)
            child.set('TW','i')
        for j in frange(2,4,0.5):
            child.set('D','10')             
            tree.write('C:PATH\Output.xml')
```

How do I change the Output.xml such that I can create i output files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `child.set('TS',str(i))`

Comment: If I have to write into multiple files, how do I change the above statement? I have edited in the question. Please and thanks!

Comment: @Potato I don't understand.. If you want to write this to another new file on every loop iteration, then you should use [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: Even if I use open, how would I make it such that there are i xml files created?

Comment: Just make `.xml` in the file name. Like `file = open('my_file.xml', 'w+')`